# How to conduct entity co-referencing and negation detection with OpenNLP?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, opennlp

Is there a way to handle negations in OpenNLP?

For instance

> "He is NOT a dangerous person."

With POS tagging we usually sense adjective "dangerous" and give a negative sentiment. Any way to figure this out?

More specific (with OpenNLP): How could entity co-referencing/relation be done?